# Kubernetes Plugin- Declarative Pipeline -ERROR: Node is not a Kubernetes node:

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

The declarative pipeline by defining yaml inside the kuberentes section of agent is not working. I was using jenkins 2.176.x LTS version. I am getting the following error in the console ***"ERROR: Node is not a Kubernetes node:"***
[image: error.jpg]
I have tried all the existing solutions available in stack overflow.

Please find the pipeline code:

```
        pipeline {
            agent {
             kubernetes {
              //cloud 'kubernetes'
              yaml """
                apiVersion: v1
               kind: Pod
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: maven
            image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine
            command: ['cat']
            tty: true
        """
            }
          }
          stages {
            stage('Run maven') {
              steps {
                container('maven') {
                  sh 'mvn -version'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

It should deploy the pod and run the command

Answer (score 1):

You must supply a label to the kubernetes block:

```
kubernetes {
  label 'mylabel'
  yaml """
  ....
}
```